# exponential commutes integral matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

This question is a similar question with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487127/exponential-commutes-integral/1487152#1487152),

I just copy the updates, since the form question has been answered.
Above is in differential form, now I consider the integral form:
Can we find some $B$ such that:
$$B\int_{t_0}^tB(s)ds\neq \int_{t_0}^tB(s)dsB\;\;but\;\;Be^{\int_{t_0}^tB(s)ds}=e^{\int_{t_0}^tB(s)ds}B$$